# Connecting to snowflake in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a very base script that works to connect to snowflake python connect but once I drop it in a jupyter notebook , I get the error below and really have no idea why?

```
import snowflake.connector
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(account='account',
                                        user='user',
                                        password='password',
                                        database='db')
```

ERROR

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py:1125, in SnowflakeConnection._authenticate(self, auth_instance)
   1124 try:
-> 1125     auth.authenticate(
   1126         auth_instance=auth_instance,
   1127         account=self.account,
   1128         user=self.user,
   1129         database=self.database,
   1130         schema=self.schema,
   1131         warehouse=self.warehouse,
   1132         role=self.role,
   1133         passcode=self._passcode,
   1134         passcode_in_password=self._passcode_in_password,
   1135         mfa_callback=self._mfa_callback,
   1136         password_callback=self._password_callback,
   1137         session_parameters=self._session_parameters,
   1138     )
   1139 except OperationalError as e:

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/auth/_auth.py:250, in Auth.authenticate(self, auth_instance, account, user, database, schema, warehouse, role, passcode, passcode_in_password, mfa_callback, password_callback, session_parameters, timeout)
    249 try:
--> 250     ret = self._rest._post_request(
    251         url,
    252         headers,
    253         json.dumps(body),
    254         timeout=auth_timeout,
    255         socket_timeout=auth_timeout,
    256     )
    257 except ForbiddenError as err:
    258     # HTTP 403

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:716, in SnowflakeRestful._post_request(self, url, headers, body, token, timeout, _no_results, no_retry, socket_timeout, _include_retry_params)
    714     pprint(ret)
--> 716 ret = self.fetch(
    717     "post",
    718     full_url,
    719     headers,
    720     data=body,
    721     timeout=timeout,
    722     token=token,
    723     no_retry=no_retry,
    724     socket_timeout=socket_timeout,
    725     _include_retry_params=_include_retry_params,
    726 )
    727 logger.debug(
    728     "ret[code] = {code}, after post request".format(
    729         code=(ret.get("code", "N/A"))
    730     )
    731 )

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:814, in SnowflakeRestful.fetch(self, method, full_url, headers, data, timeout, **kwargs)
    813 while True:
--> 814     ret = self._request_exec_wrapper(
    815         session, method, full_url, headers, data, retry_ctx, **kwargs
    816     )
    817     if ret is not None:

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:937, in SnowflakeRestful._request_exec_wrapper(self, session, method, full_url, headers, data, retry_ctx, no_retry, token, **kwargs)
    936 if not no_retry:
--> 937     raise e
    938 logger.debug("Ignored error", exc_info=True)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:868, in SnowflakeRestful._request_exec_wrapper(self, session, method, full_url, headers, data, retry_ctx, no_retry, token, **kwargs)
    867     return return_object
--> 868 self._handle_unknown_error(method, full_url, headers, data, conn)
    869 TelemetryService.get_instance().log_http_request_error(
    870     "HttpRequestUnknownError",
    871     full_url,
   (...)
    876     retry_count=retry_ctx.cnt,
    877 )

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:992, in SnowflakeRestful._handle_unknown_error(self, method, full_url, headers, data, conn)
    987 logger.error(
    988     f"Failed to get the response. Hanging? "
    989     f"method: {method}, url: {full_url}, headers:{headers}, "
    990     f"data: {data}"
    991 )
--> 992 Error.errorhandler_wrapper(
    993     conn,
    994     None,
    995     OperationalError,
    996     {
    997         "msg": f"Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: {method}, url: {full_url}",
    998         "errno": ER_FAILED_TO_REQUEST,
    999     },
   1000 )

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py:290, in Error.errorhandler_wrapper(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    274 """Error handler wrapper that calls the errorhandler method.
    275 
    276 Args:
   (...)
    287     exception to the first handler in that order.
    288 """
--> 290 handed_over = Error.hand_to_other_handler(
    291     connection,
    292     cursor,
    293     error_class,
    294     error_value,
    295 )
    296 if not handed_over:

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py:348, in Error.hand_to_other_handler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    347 elif connection is not None:
--> 348     connection.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    349     return True

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py:221, in Error.default_errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    220 done_format_msg = error_value.get("done_format_msg")
--> 221 raise error_class(
    222     msg=error_value.get("msg"),
    223     errno=None if errno is None else int(errno),
    224     sqlstate=error_value.get("sqlstate"),
    225     sfqid=error_value.get("sfqid"),
    226     query=error_value.get("query"),
    227     done_format_msg=(
    228         None if done_format_msg is None else bool(done_format_msg)
    229     ),
    230     connection=connection,
    231     cursor=cursor,
    232 )

OperationalError: 250003: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://xw81982.us-east4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=cedc0862-8df4-4cb1-a617-5216d2a16254&databaseName=Product&request_guid=435b4fa9-7df9-494c-b0b1-5238c26c032e

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 2
      1 import snowflake.connector
----> 2 conn = snowflake.connector.connect(account='xw81982.us-east4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com',
      3                                         user='03pes03',
      4                                         password='Copper333,,',
      5                                         database='Product')   

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/__init__.py:51, in Connect(**kwargs)
     50 def Connect(**kwargs) -> SnowflakeConnection:
---> 51     return SnowflakeConnection(**kwargs)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py:304, in SnowflakeConnection.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    302 self.converter = None
    303 self.__set_error_attributes()
--> 304 self.connect(**kwargs)
    305 self._telemetry = TelemetryClient(self._rest)
    307 # get the imported modules from sys.modules

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py:571, in SnowflakeConnection.connect(self, **kwargs)
    569         connection_diag.generate_report()
    570 else:
--> 571     self.__open_connection()

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py:839, in SnowflakeConnection.__open_connection(self)
    835 else:
    836     # okta URL, e.g., https://<account>.okta.com/
    837     self.auth_class = AuthByOkta(application=self.application)
--> 839 self.authenticate_with_retry(self.auth_class)
    841 self._password = None  # ensure password won't persist
    842 self.auth_class.reset_secrets()

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py:1099, in SnowflakeConnection.authenticate_with_retry(self, auth_instance)
   1096 def authenticate_with_retry(self, auth_instance) -> None:
   1097     # make some changes if needed before real __authenticate
   1098     try:
-> 1099         self._authenticate(auth_instance)
   1100     except ReauthenticationRequest as ex:
   1101         # cached id_token expiration error, we have cleaned id_token and try to authenticate again
   1102         logger.debug("ID token expired. Reauthenticating...: %s", ex)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py:1170, in SnowflakeConnection._authenticate(self, auth_instance)
   1168 except OperationalError as auth_op:
   1169     if auth_op.errno == ER_FAILED_TO_CONNECT_TO_DB:
-> 1170         raise auth_op from e
   1171     logger.debug("Continuing authenticator specific timeout handling")
   1172     continue

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py:1147, in SnowflakeConnection._authenticate(self, auth_instance)
   1145 while True:
   1146     try:
-> 1147         auth_instance.handle_timeout(
   1148             authenticator=self._authenticator,
   1149             service_name=self.service_name,
   1150             account=self.account,
   1151             user=self.user,
   1152             password=self._password,
   1153         )
   1154         auth.authenticate(
   1155             auth_instance=auth_instance,
   1156             account=self.account,
   (...)
   1166             session_parameters=self._session_parameters,
   1167         )
   1168     except OperationalError as auth_op:

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/snowflake/connector/auth/by_plugin.py:214, in AuthByPlugin.handle_timeout(***failed resolving arguments***)
    212 if not self._retry_ctx.should_retry():
    213     self._retry_ctx.reset()
--> 214     raise OperationalError(
    215         msg=f"Could not connect to Snowflake backend after {self._retry_ctx.get_current_retry_count()} attempt(s)."
    216         "Aborting",
    217         errno=ER_FAILED_TO_CONNECT_TO_DB,
    218     )
    219 else:
    220     logger.debug(
    221         f"Hit connection timeout, attempt number {self._retry_ctx.get_current_retry_count()}."
    222         " Will retry in a bit..."
    223     )

OperationalError: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s)*

Hypothesis:

**Provided account is incorrect.** - It contains full url

---

If the url is:

```
https://xxxxx.region.cloud_provider.snowflakecomputing.com
```

then account should not include `.snowflakecomputing.com`

```
import snowflake.connector
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(account='xxxxx.region.cloud_provider',
                                   user='user',
                                   password='password',
                                   database='db')
```

It is also recommended to explicitly list `role/warehouse` during the connection setup, otherwise user's default will be used.